# Node 14.4.0 | Electron 10.1.2 | WebGL context returns null in class

Tags: javascript, electron, html5-canvas, webgl

Let's say we have a class called `Render` with a constructor that needs the `window` variable to create a canvas and the WebGL context:

```
class Render
{
    constructor(WINDOW=window)
    {
        this.window = WINDOW
        this.canvas = this.window.document.createElement("canvas")
        this.gl = this.canvas.getContext("webgl2")
        // after that there's some other code but has no relation with the above
    }
}
```

when I make a 2D Context, everything works fine, but for WebGL, it returns `null` in the class.

I've tried:

1. a parameter for WebGL and/or the canvas:

```
class Render
{
    constructor(WINDOW=window,webgl,canvas)
}
```

1. a method resetting the canvas, the 2D and WebGL context
2. a function outside the class which creates a canvas
3. porting my code to browser (same result)

These are the `webPreferences` I enabled:

nodeIntegration
noteIntegrationInWorker
enableRemoteModule
webgl

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

*does webgl2 work on Chrome on the same machine?*

Yes, going to https://get.webgl.org/ show me a rotating cube and "Your browser supports WebGL". At `about:gpu` in Chrome also shows that WebGL and WebGL2 are enabled.

*does webgl1 work in Electron on the same machine?*

Yes, I already tried that but same result.

*open a window to about:gpu in Electron and see what it says*

Interesting, it's says that webgl and webgl2 are disabled, even though in `webPreferences` webgl is set to true, but now there's something else i noticed:

When I start the app, it's says to the render property for webgl context null, right? BUT if I create a canvas in the console and get the Context, it returns the webgl/webgl2 context. *Very weird*

EDIT 2:

Um, I solved it? Looks like a canvas cannot have a 2D Context AND a Webgl context at the same time...

Comment: things to check. (1) does webgl2 work on Chrome on the same machine? (2) does webgl1 work in Electron on the same machine? (3) open a window to `about:gpu` in Electron and see what it says (see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gpu-information-in-electronjs/))